# Speech problems due to braces - how to approach this during interview?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, health

I am wearing braces. Recently, a metal part was added near my palate and it's causing some lisping.

I'm going to be interviewed in a while and I'm wondering how I should approach this issue. I'm thinking about telling the interviewers at the beginning that this is only a temporary issue and that they shouldn't hesitate to ask me to repeat if they don't  understand some words.

Is this acceptable and professional?

Comment: Is it severe enough that they reasonably would not be able to understand some words?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm thinking about telling the interviewers at the beginning that this is only a temporary issue and that they shouldn't hesitate to ask me to repeat if they don't understand some words.
>
> Is this acceptable and professional?

Yes, bringing up the issue yourself at the start of the interview will likely put you and the interviewers more at ease.

It's entirely possible that the speech problems are more noticeable to you than others, but there's no harm in mentioning it.

I would only mention it once, however -- if you repeatedly apologize or draw attention to your speech, that could be more distracting.

Answer (score 2):

I think that would be fine.  They will be able to see your braces.

Answer (score 2):

Given the impediment to speech is visible, they will probably surmise your braces are the cause, and even if they aren't, lisping which doesn't interfere with being able to understand you is not in at least most instances cause for dismissing a candidate, unless for example, you are applying for a role that requires a lot of public speaking.

That being said, if you make a particularly embarrassing mistake because of the lisp, it may be an opportune time to point out the cause, but I would leave it otherwise.

Comment: "unless ... you are applying for a role that requires a lot of public speaking" - that seems like an important note, and might require being handled differently, but it also depends how severe the impediment is.